# How to create a different redirect for login and registration in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a login and registration page in Laravel. I have done that successfully but my problem is that when users login or newly register they are redirected to the same page, no thanks to the $redirectTo property in the AuthController.

**Authcontroller.php :**

```
<php
    $redirectTo = '/home';
```

How do I override this 'authcontroller' so I can have a different redirect for both `login.blade.php` and `register.blade.php`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own controllers where you sign up and login the user. That's completely up to you. The auth controller is just for you to get started...

Comment: There should be a way for me to override the login and register methods of the Authcontroller

Comment: If you take a look at the trait, you can then see the methods, you're allowed to override...